# Cannot install @angular/cli@9.1.8 after install nodejs

Tags: angular-cli, angular-cli-v9

I've tried to install @angular/cli@9.1.8 (npm install -g @angular/cli)

Then the following error message appeared:

- npm ERR! Response timeout while trying to fetch
  http://registry.npmjs.org/@angular-devkit%2fschematics (over 30000ms)

  npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
  C:\NODEJS\npm-cache_logs\2020-06-16T12_37_01_005Z-debug.log

These solutions I've tried but not work:

- uninstall nodejs, delete all nodejs files related it and trying install nodejs versions(8,10,12).
- uninstall angular(npm uninstall -g @angular/cli)
- npm install --save-dev @angular-devkit/build-angular
- npm cache clean --force
- npm install -g @angular/cli --timeout=60000
- npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/

  **Tip**:the problem appeared when I tried update angular 8 to angular 9.

[image]

[image]

Comment: are you behind a company proxy?

Comment: No, But the problem appeared when I tried update angular 8 to angular 9

Comment: do one thing, run npm cache clean --force, after than run npm i -g @angular/cli@latest

Comment: Not work, Same message

Comment: actually your network is block npm registry. are you sure, your network isn't behind a proxy blocking npm installs.

Comment: not really sure, what is your suggest for proxy blocking I can do it

Comment: try npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/ after than run same npm install command.

Comment: instead of http use https in registry url.

Comment: i have added the steps below. if they help please mark it as answer.

Comment: I tried:  npm cache clean --force / npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org / npm i -g @angular/cli@latest . but not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many days I installed Angular 9 by this steps:

- Open Windows PowerShell as admin
- npm install npm@latest -g
- npm cache clean --force
- npm install -g @angular/cli

and I've stopped **Windows defender** & **Firewall**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your npm install trying to access packages from http, it should use https url. Follow these steps :-

1. Run

   npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
2. Run
   npm cache clean --force
3. Run
   npm  i -g @angular/cli@latest

Comment: Please check out for a picture i have added above